# How to deliver custom HTML on a bottle 404 Handler?

Tags: python, error-handling, http-status-code-404, jinja2, bottle

I'm trying to use the jinja2_view plugin to render a template from a custom error handler like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, abort, jinja2_view

app = Bottle()

@jinja2_view('index.html')
@app.get('/')
def index():
    abort(404)

@jinja_view('404.html')
@app.error(404)
def handle404(error):
    return error
```

But this doesn't work.

I tried returning a string from the handler like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, abort, jinja2_view

app = Bottle()

@jinja2_view('index.html')
@app.get('/')
def index():
    abort(404)


@app.error(404)
def handle404(error):
    return '<h1>Custom code</h1>'
```

It worked, but it's not the preferred option.

How i can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always instantiate your own Jinja Environment like this:

```
from bottle import Bottle, abort, jinja2_view
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'))

app = Bottle()

@jinja2_view('index.html')
@app.get('/')
def index():
    abort(404)


@app.error(404)
def handle404(error):
    template = env.get_template('404.html')
    return template.render()
```

The bad thing about this aproach is that all the configuration made on the bottle jinja plugin is lost and you have to configure this again.

Good news is that there is another jinja plugin available in bottle, named jinja2_template, that is not to be annotated, but to be returned in the request.

```
from bottle import Bottle, abort, jinja2_view, jinja2_template

app = Bottle()

@jinja2_view('index.html')
@app.get('/')
def index():
    abort(404)


@app.error(404)
def handle404(error):
    return jinja2_template('404.html')
```

So if you can change the code to this you can load the template from jinja correctly, using the same configurations from the bottle jinja plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are applied in reverse order. In your code example, you apply the view decorators *after* the route decorators, meaning that the undecorated handler functions are bound to the app and no templates are rendered. Your get-route won't work either. Simply switch the order of the decorators:

```py
from bottle import Bottle, abort, jinja2_view as view

app = Bottle()

@app.get('/')
@view('index.html')
def index():
    abort(404)

@app.error(404)
@view('404.html')
def handle404(error):
    return error
```